# How can I exit this Recursive loop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, algorithm, fibonacci

I am having tough time in figuring out how to exit from my recursive function

My Code is

```
    public Main()
    {
         GetFibonacci(5,20);
    }

 private void GetFibonacci(int StartNUmber, int LastNumber)
    {
        if (StartNUmber < LastNumber)
        {
            if (FibonacciRecursiveList.Count == 0 || FibonacciRecursiveList.Count == 1)
            {
                FibonacciRecursiveList.Add(StartNUmber);
            }
            else
            {
                int value = FibonacciRecursiveList[FibonacciRecursiveList.Count - 1] + FibonacciRecursiveList[FibonacciRecursiveList.Count - 2];
                FibonacciRecursiveList.Add(value);
            }
            StartNUmber++;
            GetFibonacci(StartNUmber, LastNumber);
        }
        else
        {
           return;
        }
    }
```

On reaching the Outer else loop the  code still runs

Please help

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the code to verify that the `return` statement is actually being reached? I doubt the compiler is broken and continues to loop even though the code says not to.

Comment: Why are you calling the function recursively? With a list holding previous values (`FibonacciRecursiveList`) you really don't need a recursive call.

Comment: That's impossible, I just tried running this and - it exited without a problem.. not into an infinite loop. Can you post the full code?

Comment: Thats my complete code Aniket

Comment: @Kyle the code as it stands out, will not compile.

Comment: what happens if `StartNumber` gets 20? Does it start over again at 5?

Comment: @Terry how can it possibly go to 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it gets to the return statement, it won't immediately return to the main function. It has to return through the recursive calls 15 times to get back to main.

There is very little overhead in returning up the stack. This recursive approach is fine as long as it doesn't go too deep. If you wanted to go up to a large number, then you would have to recode it as a loop.

Comment: I guess thats my solution ...but what am i missing..how can i avoid it??

Comment: You don't want to avoid it. All recursive algorithms work that way.

Comment: @Kyle: This is how recursive function works. 
If you don't want it, you could try rewriting your logic/function using While loop and break; instead of recursion.

Comment: Thats why recursive is not always the best way, try recoding in an iterative algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of the recursive call is wrong, however, your recursive call really finishes without problems.

I guess, what you see as

> On reaching the outer else loop the code still runs

is the recursive call! When the code reaches the `return` statement, the method is already called 16 times! So the return statement will get us back to where the method was called, which is the last line of the `if` block. After that, this method call is also finished, so the execution will return to the previous call of the function, which happens to be 14th call, on the same line. This continues for all the calls, until the execution returns to the `Main`.

You can easily implement what you want without a recursive call:

```
public void Main()
{
    FibonacciRecursiveList = new List<int>();
    GetFibonacci(5,20);
}


private void GetFibonacci(int StartNUmber, int LastNumber)
{
    while (StartNUmber < LastNumber)
    {
        if (FibonacciRecursiveList.Count == 0 || FibonacciRecursiveList.Count == 1)
        {
            FibonacciRecursiveList.Add(StartNUmber);
        }
        else
        {
            int value = FibonacciRecursiveList[FibonacciRecursiveList.Count - 1] + FibonacciRecursiveList[FibonacciRecursiveList.Count - 2];
            FibonacciRecursiveList.Add(value);
        }
        StartNUmber++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `GetFibbonaci` returns or the stack overflows and a `StackOverflowException` gets thrown. (It is trivial to deduce this as there are no loops, only recursion.) Unless you know an exception is being thrown, it must be returning.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you above code runs OK with the below value in the FibonacciRecursiveList.
But, Not sure if this is the expected/intended output.

```
[0] 5   int
    [1] 6   int
    [2] 11  int
    [3] 17  int
    [4] 28  int
    [5] 45  int
    [6] 73  int
    [7] 118 int
    [8] 191 int
    [9] 309 int
    [10]    500 int
    [11]    809 int
    [12]    1309    int
    [13]    2118    int
    [14]    3427    int
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I run:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Main1{
public Main1()
    {
         FibonacciRecursiveList = new List<int>();
         GetFibonacci(5,20);
    }
 private List<int> FibonacciRecursiveList;
 private void GetFibonacci(int StartNUmber, int LastNumber)
    {
        if (StartNUmber < LastNumber)
        {
            if (FibonacciRecursiveList.Count == 0 || FibonacciRecursiveList.Count == 1)
            {
                FibonacciRecursiveList.Add(StartNUmber);
            }
            else
            {
                int value = FibonacciRecursiveList[FibonacciRecursiveList.Count - 1] + FibonacciRecursiveList

[FibonacciRecursiveList.Count - 2];
                FibonacciRecursiveList.Add(value);
            }
            StartNUmber++;
            GetFibonacci(StartNUmber, LastNumber);
        }
        else
        {
           return;
        }
    }

 public static void Main(string[] args) {

     Main1 main = new Main1();
     foreach(int a in main.FibonacciRecursiveList){
         Console.WriteLine(a);
     }
 }
}
```

No stackoverflow or infinite loop!

Output:

```
5
6
11
17
28
45
73
118
191
309
500
809
1309
2118
3427
```

Answer (score 0):

> On reaching the Outer else loop the code still runs?

i think actual problem is StartNUmber values is not updated BACK recursively , for this use pass by reference

the real code becomes

```
 List<int> FibonacciRecursiveList = new List<int>();
    private void GetFibonacci(ref int StartNUmber, ref int LastNumber)
{
    if (StartNUmber < LastNumber)
    {
        if (FibonacciRecursiveList.Count == 0 || FibonacciRecursiveList.Count == 1)
        {
            FibonacciRecursiveList.Add(StartNUmber);
        }
        else
        {
            int value = FibonacciRecursiveList[FibonacciRecursiveList.Count - 1] + FibonacciRecursiveList[FibonacciRecursiveList.Count - 2];
            FibonacciRecursiveList.Add(value);
        }
        StartNUmber++;
        GetFibonacci(ref StartNUmber, ref LastNumber);
    }
    else
    {
       return;
    }
}
```

then call

```
  int T = 1;
  int T2 = 12;
  GetFibonacci(ref  T, ref  T2);
```

Let Me know whether i am correct ?